# Android DatePickerDialog with changing dates

Tags: android

I want to fix the month and year in datePickerDialog but want the user to pick date on his own. Is it possible?
ex: DatePickerDialog will be fixed with month May and year 2015, user can now only change the dates between 1 to 31

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321789/android-datepicker-change-to-only-month-and-year

Comment: @Priya please find my below solution for that

Comment: If you just cant answer then its ohk , but why are you downvoting the question??Its a valid question and its according to my project need.

Comment: I did not down vote you..Even i tried to help you to short out from these problem.Check the below answer

Comment: @Ravindra I am not saying to you yar, am just saying to those who dont have guts to answer the question but just know only how to downvote the answer

Comment: @Priya...I have updated the code...Please check below

Comment: @Priya ...Did yours problem resolve??

Comment: Finally I solved my problem,I have mentioned my answer below,,you can see there for any help,,,

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem in the following way:

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, myDateSetListener, year, month,
                            day);
                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, userMonthValue);

                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, userYearValue);

                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
                    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(cal.getTimeInMillis() - 1000);

                    // code to set max date
                    cal = Calendar.getInstance();

                    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, userMonthValue);

                    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, userYearValue);
                    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, cal.getMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
                    dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(cal.getTimeInMillis() - 1000);
```

Now my date picker dialog is fixed for month and year,,,and user is able to change only the dates between 1 and 30 or 31

Answer (score 0):

***You can use below lines of code***

```
 public class First extends Activity {
DatePicker _date;
Date date_current;
Date date_future;
int days_count=0;

@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
@SuppressLint("NewApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first);
    Calendar ci = Calendar.getInstance();
    String CiDateTime = ci.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
            (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + 
            ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy");


    try {
        date_current =  f.parse(CiDateTime);
        long milliseconds = date_current.getTime();
        _date.setMinDate(milliseconds);//here is _date is DatePicker Object

        int monthMaxDays = ci.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); 
        if(monthMaxDays>ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH))
        {
            days_count = monthMaxDays-ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            String CiDateMax = ci.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "-" + 
                    (ci.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1) + "-" + 
                    ci.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)+days_count;
            date_future =  f.parse(CiDateMax);
            long milliseconds_MAx = date_future.getTime();
            _date.setMaxDate(milliseconds_MAx);
        }
        else
        {
            _date.setMaxDate(milliseconds);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: @priya..Is it workable for you..If there is any concern than plz let me know

Comment: using ur code today date will be set as the mindate, but i want user to set date himself while month and year is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the underlying DatePicker from a DatePickerDialog (by simply calling getDatePicker()) and set its bounds using :

- [setMinDate(long minDate)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate%28long%29)
- [setMaxDate(long maxDate)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMaxDate%28long%29)

Comment: @Priya if you want to more explain with example than let me know.