# DatePicker Dialog with only month and year in android 6.0

Tags: android, datepicker, fragment, android-6.0-marshmallow

After reasearching a lot, I could implement the `Datepicker` without month and year for the APIs above 11 except API 23(marshmallow), because in the APIs below 23, the `DialogFragment` was containing 3 fields separately and by hiding the date field it was achieved and now the fragment is a calendar and now how can we implement the Fragment without date field.

[image]

Comment: Here is a link [Android DatePicker change to only Month and Year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321789/android-datepicker-change-to-only-month-and-year) that you might looking for. Thanks. :)

Comment: I have seen that prior but it didn't work at all.

Comment: @harshavardhan How did you implemented it?