# Select month and year range (without days) Android

Tags: android, date, range, datechooser

maybe someone know component (view) to select range? like:

```
Select from:      select to:
month+year        month+year
```

[image: like this photo, but needed range selection]

i finded datePicker views on gitHub only with days selection range:
[github](https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker)

but in this component draws dates :(

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321789/android-datepicker-change-to-only-month-and-year look here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android DatePicker change to only Month and Year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21321789/android-datepicker-change-to-only-month-and-year)

Comment: is not duplicate. All this answers not about RANGE selections

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/31653048/8905812

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this question: 
[Android DatePicker change to only Month and Year](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21321789/8035153)

I would post that in comments, but I don't have permission to do so.

There is more options than in Pratik Kate's answer.

edit: I know those solutions do not offer range selection, but I think that could be easily solved using two pickers - 'from-to'.

See the screenshots e.g. in this project: [Material Date and Time Picker with Range Selection](https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker)

I think it can look pretty good. I can imagine many users would be confused when asked to select range using only one picker (having to use some sort of long-press or drag event?).

Comment: yes, i founded earlier this DatePicker. This component dont have range selection functional

Comment: yes. You right. I think to make dialog with 2 DatePicker with no DATE selecting

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code. It will show a DatePicker with only the year and month (without day)

```
private DatePickerDialog createDialogWithoutDateField() {
    DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this, null, 2014, 1, 24);
    try {
        java.lang.reflect.Field[] datePickerDialogFields = dpd.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
        for (java.lang.reflect.Field datePickerDialogField : datePickerDialogFields) {
            if (datePickerDialogField.getName().equals("mDatePicker")) {
                datePickerDialogField.setAccessible(true);
                DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) datePickerDialogField.get(dpd);
                java.lang.reflect.Field[] datePickerFields = datePickerDialogField.getType().getDeclaredFields();
                for (java.lang.reflect.Field datePickerField : datePickerFields) {
                    Log.i("test", datePickerField.getName());
                    if ("mDaySpinner".equals(datePickerField.getName())) {
                        datePickerField.setAccessible(true);
                        Object dayPicker = datePickerField.get(datePicker);
                        ((View) dayPicker).setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return dpd;
}
```

This method returns a date picker dialog. So , in your button's onClick method add the following code to display your dialog.

```
createDialogWithoutDateField().show();
```

Comment: You can check this one too : https://github.com/code-troopers/android-betterpickers

Comment: for answer: This code for selecting just month + year but not range.
for Kate answer: good but no month+year ranges :(